# Using a while loop to declare an impossible output

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class volumeConeD

{//class
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {//main

        Scanner keyBoard = new Scanner(System.in);//input for keyBoard
        //variables
        double volume;
        double radius;
        double hieght;
        double pie = 3.14;
        double yes = 1.0;
        boolean volumeTwo = true;


        while(volumeTwo == 0){
            System.out.print("Volume of a Cone... V=1/3(3.14)r^2(h)");
            System.out.println ();
            System.out.println ();

            radius = getRadius(radius); //call to method
            System.out.print("Enter a Height      ");
            hieght = keyBoard.nextDouble ();
            //math
            volume = .33333 * pie * radius * radius * hieght;
            System.out.printf ("Volume =       " + volume);

        }//end of while         
    }//end of main
    public static double getRadius (double radius)
    {
        Scanner keyBoard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter Radius Squared Number      "); 
        radius = keyBoard.nextDouble ();
        return radius;
    }
}//end of program
```

So here is my issue. I have to write this so that if the answer ends up being Volume = 0 the program must end. I have to use a while loop and that method to input the radius. I keep getting this error and I can't figure out why.

```
               error
                       volumeConeD.java:25: error: incomparable types: boolean and int
while(volumeTwo == 0){
                ^
1 error.
```

I understand what the error means but I cannot figure out how to fix it. Please help
NEW EDIT...also in the while loop it must read, while(Volume == 0).

Comment: This error message is crystal clear: you're trying to compare boolean with 0, and that's wrong in Java.

Comment: 'cause you can't compare a Boolean to a int.  It says it in the error.  volumeTwo never gets re-assigned anywhere either.

Comment: why do you even have `volumeTwo`? You never really use it. Maybe you meant to check that `(volume != 0)`. Something like `do{ ... } while(volume != 0)`

Comment: Please elaborate on what your program does/is supposed to do (specifically the function of `VolumeTwo`) . It is very difficult to guess at what you want to happen.

Comment: I need it to repeat so long as the Volume does not equal 0.

Comment: 1) Don't define pie; use `Math.PI` instead. it is more accurate.

2) Don't multiply by .33333, divide by 3 instead. 

3) Why are you calling a method to get the radius via `getRadius()` and not for height also?

4)would recommend you just use `println()` instead of `print()` and `printf()` since you aren't formatting the output anyway

Answer (score 1):

Use `while(volumeTwo)` if you want it to continue while `volumeTwo` is `true` or `while(!volumeTwo)` if you want it to continue while `volumeTwo` is `false`.

Comment: I have done this but my professor also wants volumeTwo to equal 0 in the loop, like how i wrote it. I should have said this up top**

Comment: Apparently you misunderstand your professor. If `volumeTwo` variable is not defined as a numeric variable, you won't be able to assign numeric values to it, plain and simple.

Comment: redFIVE, that worked but now i get an error for calling my method that variable radius might not have been initialized.

Comment: Ok, so initialize it.... Google is a wonderful tool to find out answers to these silly basic questions.

Comment: I always refer back to my old programs that work when i write similar code and in comparison to those i do believe i have initialized it, which is why i'm confused and on here

Answer (score 0):

You try to compare `boolean` with `0` , Hmm

```
boolean volumeTwo = true;
while(volumeTwo == 0)
```

Use

```
 while(volumeTwo == true)
```

or

```
while(volumeTwo)
```

Comment: Err. How is that different? or how does it help?

Comment: @RohitJain it compiles. Big difference for me.

Comment: This is the same thing I have or I'm just not sure what you meant.

Comment: @user2755775 I get an error: `The operator == is undefined for the argument type(s) boolean, int`

Comment: this is Java, not C. in c false is defined as 0. However in Java you can't compare ints and booleans directly: they are of different types.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of `volumeTwo` altogether. You care if `volume` is 0, so just change the while loop to `while(volume!=0)` and make sure the volume is initialized to something besides 0.

Answer (score -1):

I think following is what you are trying to achieve. Please see the comments which are marked with <======= :

```
    ... 
    //boolean volumeTwo = true; // <======= Manoj - COMMENT THIS LINE  
    double volumeTwo = 1.0; // <=========== Manoj - any non-zero for that matter
    ... 

    ... 
    while(volumeTwo != 0.0){
    ... 
              //math
      volume = .33333 * pie * radius * radius * hieght;
      System.out.printf ("Volume =       " + volume);
      volumeTwo = volume; // <=============== Manoj - update volumeTwo with calculated volume 
                          // <===============       - when volumeTwo becomes 0.0 loop quits
```

Comment: you really dont need to repost all of his code for a simple answer

Comment: This did not work, I get a lot of incompatable types for the error messeges.